# XMLHttpRequest undefined, angular mock-ajax does not listen to ajax calls by the source code?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, protractor

I am implementing jasmine for testing my front-end along with protractor and I want to mock some server responses. I am currently trying to make jasmine-ajax work and I am having issues with listening in on the ajax calls being made.

I think the problem stems from the mock-ajax file not being able to access the XMLHttpRequest object.

I was getting getJasmineRequireObj() and XMLHttpRequest are undefined errors, so I fixed it by adding

```
global.XMLHttpRequest = require('xmlhttprequest').XMLHttpRequest;
```

directly to the mock-ajax.js source file.

However, this fix doesn't solve what I am trying to do.

From within test specs, I can detect ajax calls:

Works:

```
require('../mock-ajax.js');
...
it ('should allow admin to delete user', function () {

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open("GET", "/users");
    xhr.send();

    page.deleteButton.click();

    expect(jasmine.Ajax.requests.mostRecent()).toBeDefined(true);
    var request = jasmine.Ajax.requests.mostRecent();
    request.respondWith({
    "status": 200,
    "contentType": 'application/json',
    "responseText": 'hello'
    });

    expect(request.method).toBe('GET');
});
```

DOES  NOT work:

```
require('../mock-ajax.js');
...
it ('should allow admin to delete user', function () {
    page.deleteButton.click();

    expect(jasmine.Ajax.requests.mostRecent()).toBeDefined(true);
    var request = jasmine.Ajax.requests.mostRecent();
    request.respondWith({
    "status": 200,
    "contentType": 'application/json',
    "responseText": 'hello'
    });

    expect(request.method).toBe('DELETE');
});
```

The page.deleteButton.click(); makes an ajax call from the browser, but this call is not detected from jasmine.Ajax.requests.mostRecent().

How can I make jasmine detect ajax calls made outside of the test-spec, or is that not possible? Is it that jasmine cannot detect calls made in the browser, since I am using protractor? Also, I do not have jasmine specRunner.html and my file directory is part of a large project so it may not fit the jasmine file structure for finding the source file; however, I am using protractor, so I'm not sure if this would be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is a project [jasmine-ajax](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine-ajax) which aims to help give you what you need here.